# Import SVG as a component in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, svg, import, gatsby

I've seen the following solution:

```
import { ReactComponent as Img } from 'path/to/file.svg'
```

But in Gatsby, this doesn't work. I know exist plugins for this, but maybe it can be done more easily.

Answer (score 18):

As you said, there are plugins to achieve this, which means a cleaner code (not the full SVG tag inlined in the component) with the same final result. Using [`gatsby-plugin-react-svg`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-react-svg/) plugin you just need to import your SVG like this:

```
import Icon from "./path/assets/icon.svg";
```

To install, you only need to add the dependency using `npm` or `yarn` and in your `gatsby-config.js` use this snippet:

```
{
  resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-react-svg',
  options: {
    rule: {
      include: /assets/
    }
  }
}
```

*Note that `/assets/` is an including rule based on a regular expression so the value must be your SVG folder (i.e: `/svg/`) and **must only contain `.svg` files**. In other words, if your path is `/images/svg/` your including rule can only contain `/svg/` (you can also add the full path but you'll need to escape slashes).*

Afterward, you will need to style the SVG if their inline styles don't apply.

---

If you want to follow the non-plugin approach you can simply use a React-based approach, just creating a component that returns the SVG:

```
export const YourSvgComponent = () => (
  <svg
    version="1.1"
    baseProfile="full"
    width="300"
    height="200"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  >
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
    <circle cx="150" cy="100" r="80" fill="green" />
    <text x="150" y="125" font-size="60" text-anchor="middle" fill="white">
      SVG
    </text>
  </svg>
);
```

Now you just need to import it and use it.

Comment: `gatsby-node.js` or `gatsby-config.js`?

Comment: Do you have any idea why the svg might just not be appearing? The div that it is inside is empty

Comment: These are the files I'm using https://github.com/samgermain/somefiles . I'll try to make an MRE and post a new questions

Comment: The SVG is not loading? The SVG folder must only contain SVG files

Comment: [Well I made one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63517356/receiving-invalidcharactererror-string-contains-an-invalid-character-from-imp), but it gets a different error

Comment: Non plugin approach doesn’t work in Gatsby.

Answer (score 7):

1. Add new package:

`npm install gatsby-plugin-react-svg`

or

`yarn add gatsby-plugin-react-svg`

2. Configure at `gatsby-config.js`:

```
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-react-svg',
      options: {
        rule: {
          include: /\.inline\.svg$/,
        },
      },
    },
```

Here's an example of what this file might look like when completed

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Gatsby`,
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-react-svg',
      options: {
        rule: {
          include: /assets/,
        },
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

3. Rename your files to something like `example.inline.svg`
4. Import:

```
import Illustration from './illustration.inline.svg'
```

5. Usage:

```
<Illustration className="example" />
```

All the information from [official Gatsby guide](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-react-svg/)

Answer (score 0):

Just do like this...

```js
import YourDesiredName from 'path/to/file.svg'
```

Comment: Not exactly. This you can use as src of img tag. And this method: import { ReactComponent as Img } from 'path/to/file.svg'
  allows you to import inline svg.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using a setup that has [SVGR](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-svgr/) installed by default.

You can easily get this to work by installing this [SVGR plugin for Gatsby](https://react-svgr.com/).

```bash
npm install @svgr/webpack gatsby-plugin-svgr
```

Then add it to your Gatsby config:

```js
// gatsby-config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    'gatsby-plugin-svgr',
  ],
}
```

And use it as you mentioned in your question:

```js
import { ReactComponent as Img } from 'path/to/file.svg'
```

I have just tested it and it works great!