# Receiving "InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character" from importing svgs with gatsby-plugin-react-svg

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, gatsby

I was using font-awesome svg icons, but I realized that they might be having a significant effect on the LCP of my website, so I'm trying to replace them. I went into my html and copied the svg code, and put these svg components into svg files. They open as images in my photoshop knockoff so I figured they should be good.

When I try to include them in on my page using

```
import FacebookIcon from '../images/svg/facebookF.svg'
import Email from '../images/svg/email.svg'

      <FacebookIcon />
      <Email />
```

And adding the following to my `gatsby-config.js` (after installing `gatsby-plugin-react-svg`

```
{
  resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-react-svg',
  options: {
    rule: {
      include: "/src/images/svg/"
    }
  }
}
```

I receive the error

```
InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character
```

---

This error is happening in my MRE, which you can view on this [Github repo](https://github.com/stackoverflowsam93/gatsby-svg-error). In my actual program the svgs were just not showing up, but the web page loaded fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The included folder is a regular expression so, it must only contain a single path,`/svg/` in your case. In addition, you need to remove the double quotes (what is causing your error since it's an invalid character):

```
{
  resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-react-svg',
  options: {
    rule: {
      include: /svg/
    }
  }
}
```

The rest of the code looks good.

Keep in mind that if the SVG shares any `ID` inside, it may cause severe issues since they will be replaced for the following inlined SVG. The `ID`s inside the SVG shapes must be different for each vector.

Comment: Is there no way to include more than one path? What if all these paths end with `svg` (e.g. images/comp1/svg, images/comp2/svg ...)

Comment: @Sam you can try but Gatsby won't be able to infer and create components based on multiple SVG folders. In addition, makes more sense and makes your structure cleaner to keep the assets in the same folder wrapped by type

Answer (score 8):

From the create-react-app docs for adding SVG images *as* react components

> Note: this feature is available with `react-scripts@2.0.0` and higher,
> and `react@16.3.0` and higher.

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/

Try

```
import { ReactComponent as FacebookIcon } from '../images/svg/facebookF.svg';
import { ReactComponent as Email } from '../images/svg/email.svg';

...

  <FacebookIcon />
  <Email />
```

Answer (score 1):

With react-scripts 5.0.1 + React 18.2.0 + TypeScript, I'm having to do this:

```js
// custom.d.ts (in project root)
declare module "*.svg" {
  const content: string;
  export default content;
}
```

```js
// MyComponent.tsx
import image from "./image.svg";

const MyComponent = () => {
  return <img src={image} />;
};
```

[Contrary to the docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/#adding-svgs), so can't promise this is the perfect way to do it. Looks elegant enough to me though.

For background info about `custom.d.ts`, see [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45887328/3018750).

Comment: This but with <img worked for me