# Troubleshooting SVG error in Gatsby build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, svg, gatsby

I'm trying to get a simple Gatsby site online -- `gatsby develop` works fine but on `gatsby build` I get this error message:

[image]

```sh
UNHANDLED REJECTION 
- Error in parsing SVG: 
- Unencoded <
- Line: 0
- Column: 2
- Char: <
```

I'm not explicitly using any SVGs so struggling to troubleshoot this - any advice?

My project is [here](https://github.com/whitakk/gatsby-whitakk), adapted from the [lumen starter theme](https://github.com/alxshelepenok/gatsby-starter-lumen).

Comment: How and where are you using a SVG asset? You have a `cpu.svg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your [Icon.js (line 14)](https://github.com/whitakk/gatsby-whitakk/blob/master/src/components/Icon/Icon.js#L14) file you are using a `<svg>`. This is causing your issue:

```
// @flow strict
import React from 'react';
import styles from './Icon.module.scss';

type Props = {
  name: string,
  icon: {
    viewBox?: string,
    path?: string
  }
};

const Icon = ({ name, icon }: Props) => (
  <svg className={styles['icon']} viewBox={icon.viewBox}>
    <title>{name}</title>
    <path d={icon.path} />
  </svg>
);

export default Icon;
```

When dealing with SVG I would recommend using [`gatsby-plugin-react-svg`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-react-svg/) or using a React built-in usage.

- With `gatsby-plugin-react-svg` you just to isolate the SVG in a separate folder that must only contain SVGs):

  ```
  {
     resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-react-svg',
     options: {
       rule: {
         include: /assets/
       }
     }
  }
  ```

  Then import it as a React component:

  ```
  import Icon from "./path/assets/icon.svg";

  // ...

  <Icon />;
  ```
- React built-in usage (only available with `react-scripts@2.0.0` or higher, and `react@16.3.0` or higher, more details in https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/):

  ```
    import { ReactComponent as FacebookIcon } from '../images/svg/facebookF.svg';
    import { ReactComponent as Email } from '../images/svg/email.svg';

    ...

      <FacebookIcon />
      <Email />
  ```

Since you are extending from a starter theme, remove that component and it's using from your project and add it on-demand if needed.

You can read [this StackOverflow answe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61161331/5585371)r for further details about dealing SVG in Gatsby.

Comment: Much thanks - I understand the issue better now but still struggling to figure out how to solve it. If I track right, the SVGs that actually use Icon.js are created from predefined path objects (Contacts.js -> getIcon -> icons.js) and so I can't figure out how to import the icons as react components directly.

And I tried just removing all the icons from the Contacts sidebar, which seemed like it should have fixed the problem, but I get the same error.

Comment: I've added two ways of importing SVG as React component directly. One using plugins and one with built-in way

Comment: Thanks, for some reason when I just reloaded the page this morning (without the icons) it worked even though it wasn't working last night