# Gatsby\React - window.location.href not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I need help with my code. The thing I want create is to change className according to page url 
So when I scroll or go to page /kontakt I want to change  class from "hamburger" to "hamburger active".
I also tried regex. 
 Any ideas?

Here is code:

```
const HamMenu = ()=> {
    const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false)
    const [burger, setBurger] = useState(false)
    const url = window.location.href;

    const showSidebar = () => setSidebar(!sidebar)
    const changeColor = () => {
        if((window.scrollY >= 60) || (url.indexOf("kontakt") > -1)){
            setBurger(true);
        } else {
            setBurger(false);
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', changeColor);

    return (
        <StyledMenu>

            <div>
                <Link to="#" className={sidebar ? 'menu-bars open' : 'menu-bars'} >
                    <FontAwesomeIcon 
                        icon={faBars} 
                        size="2x" 
                        className={burger ? 'hamburger active' : 'hamburger'} 
                        onClick={showSidebar}
                    />
                </Link>
            </div>
```

Comment: I don't think this is why your code "isn't working" (we probably need more details for that - *what* isn't working?),  but it's a really bad idea to use `window.addEventListener` inside the main component body. This will result in a new event listener being added every time the component rerenders for any reason! You should add this inside a `useEffect` call, and return a function that uses `removeEventListener` to clean this up when your component unmounts.

Comment: change color on scroll is working but when I go to page "/kontakt" nothing happen. This is of course component named HamMenu. Thanks for tip with useEffect

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is there - but basic things first, have you tried stepping through your code? Is it getting to the `setBurger(true)` call? If not, check what `url` is. If is is, check the class in your DOM and make sure your CSS is correct to have it the colour you want. Etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dealing with `window` in Gatsby could be a little bit tricky because two fundamental reasons:

- `window` object is only defined in the browser, so it will work perfectly under `gatsby develop` but you will need to add a "hack" to avoid a code-breaking in the `gatsby build` (because there's [no `window` in the Node server](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/)).
- Treating the `window` outside React ecosystem, may break the rehydration of the components. This means that React won't potentially know what components need to re-render on-demand, causing unmounted components, especially when navigating forward and backward using the browser's history.

There are a few workarounds to achieve what you're trying to do.

Gatsby, by default, provides a [`location` `prop`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/) in all top-level components (pages). So you can pass it to any child components at any time to change the class name based on its value:

```
const IndexPage = ({ location }) =>{

return <Layout>
   <HamMenu location={location} />
   <h1> some content</h1>
</Layout>
}
```

Then, in your `<HamMenu>` component:

```
const HamMenu = ({ location })=> {
    const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false)
    const [burger, setBurger] = useState(false)
    const url = window.location.href;

    const showSidebar = () => setSidebar(!sidebar)
    const changeColor = () => {
        if((window.scrollY >= 60) || (url.indexOf("kontakt") > -1)){
            setBurger(true);
        } else {
            setBurger(false);
        }
    }

  useEffect(() => {
    if(typeof window !== "undefined"){
    const url = window.location.href

    const changeColor = () => {
      setBurger(window.scrollY >= 60 || url.contains("kontakt"))
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', changeColor)

   return () => {
     window.removeEventListener('scroll', changeColor)
    }
   }
  }, [])


    return (
        <StyledMenu>

            <div>
                <Link to="#" className={sidebar ? 'menu-bars open' : 'menu-bars' location.pathname.includes("your-page")? ''some-class' : 'some-other-class' } >
                    <FontAwesomeIcon 
                        icon={faBars} 
                        size="2x" 
                        className={burger ? 'hamburger active' : 'hamburger'} 
                        onClick={showSidebar}
                    />
                </Link>
            </div>
```

I would suggest another approach to get the scroll position rather than using directly the `window`, using React-based approach to avoid what I was pointing before ([How to add a scroll event to a header in Gatsby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66095185/how-to-add-a-scroll-event-to-a-header-in-gatsby)).

However, I've fixed your initial approach, wrapping it inside a `useEffect` with empty `deps` (`[]`). This function will be triggered once the DOM tree is loaded, to avoid the code-breaking `window` use that I was talking about. Alternatively to `url.indexOf("kontakt") > -1` you may want to use `url.includes("kontakt")` which is way more readable.

Regarding the rest, it's quite self-explanatory. Destructuring the `location` `props` you get access to a bunch of data, the `pathname` property holds the page name so based on that, you can add a ternary condition wherever you want, such as `location.pathname.includes("your-page") ? ''some-class' : 'some-other-class'` (`includes` is more semantic in my opinion).

As you see, I've fixed your approach but I've also added a React/Gatsby-based one, choose what makes you feel comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

React components rendering server-side (such as during `gatsby build`) do not have access to `window`, and in order to avoid breaking hydration, the first render needs to match what is rendered server-side. For these reasons, you'll want to use `useEffect` to make client-side changes that rely on `window` after the component mounts.

Note that this solution is going to perform rather poorly since `changeColor` is calling `setBurger` on each `scroll` event, which prompts the component to be re-rendered (even if the value is the same). You'll want to add a debounce or throttle routine to mitigate this.

```
const HamMenu = ()=> {
  const [burger, setBurger] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    const url = window.location.href

    const changeColor = () => {
      setBurger(window.scrollY >= 60 || url.contains("kontakt"))
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', changeColor)

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', changeColor)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <StyledMenu>
      <div>
        <Link to="#" className={sidebar ? 'menu-bars open' : 'menu-bars'} > 
          <FontAwesomeIcon
            icon={faBars}
            size="2x" 
            className={burger ? 'hamburger active' : 'hamburger'} 
          />
        </Link>
      </div>
    </StyledMenu>
  )
}
```