# How to render svg files with Gatsby Image?

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, graphql, gatsby

Currently in my project I have a folder with all my svg files, the query to get them from graphql is as follows:

```
query AssetsPhotos {
  allFile(filter: {extension: {regex: "/(svg)/"}, relativeDirectory: {eq: "svg"}}) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but unlike image files (.png, jpg, etc) I don't have the GatsbyImageData option, how could I render them if I want something like this:

```
 {SgvsData.map(({ image,id,title}) => (

              <GatsbyImage image={getImage(image.gatsbyImageData)} alt={title} key={id} />

          ))}
```

I tried options like publicUrl, children and childImageSharp, but the image doesn't render.
Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 4):

You can query the SVG via `publicURL` but you can't render it using GatsbyImage. So just use the `<img>` tag, and you **don't need a plugin**.

```
query MyQuery {
  allFile(filter: {extension: {in: "svg"}}) {
    nodes {
      publicURL
    }
  }
}
```

And than to render it:

```
<img src={...publicURL} alt=""/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't render SVG files with Gatsby Image, but you don't need to.

You could use [gatsby-plugin-svgr-loader](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-svgr-loader/) (I like it more than `gatsby-plugin-react-svg` but they do essentially the same):

```
import Icon from "./path/assets/icon.svg";

// ...

<Icon />;
```

In this case the plugin is configured to process svg files from a path matching `/assets/`

```
{
    resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-svgr-loader',
    options: {
        rule: {
          include: /assets/
        }
    }
}
```

The other way around is to write svg code directly in your component:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" strokeWidth={2}>
  <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M15 17h5l-1.405-1.405A2.032 2.032 0 0118 14.158V11a6.002 6.002 0 00-4-5.659V5a2 2 0 10-4 0v.341C7.67 6.165 6 8.388 6 11v3.159c0 .538-.214 1.055-.595 1.436L4 17h5m6 0v1a3 3 0 11-6 0v-1m6 0H9" />
</svg>
```

The above example is a bell icon exported as jsx from [heroicons](https://heroicons.com/)

Answer (score 1):

> How to render svg files with Gatsby Image?

Short answer: you can't

`gatsby-plugin-sharp` and `gatsby-plugin-image` doesn't support SVGs or GIFs (check: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/10297#issuecomment-444419483)

As you pointed out, there's no `GatsbyImageData` because Gatsby's transformers and sharps ([`gatsby-transformer-sharp`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-transformer-sharp/) but especially [`gatsby-plugin-sharp`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-sharp/)) doesn't support SVG. As they are not able to interpret SVG assets, they are not able to create the GraphQL nodes.

That said, there are multiple ways of loading an SVG in a React/Gatsby project:

- Creating a component that returns the SVG directly.
- Using `gatsby-plugin-react-svg`: follow [Import SVG as a component in Gatsby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61158924/import-svg-as-a-component-in-gatsby/61161331#61161331) for more details