# Gatsby StaticImage quality is bad

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-image

I use StaticImage in Gatsby. And when I compare `<img>`and `<StaticImage>`, StaticImage's quality is bad, even though I make `quality={90} or {100}`. Is there way to make the quality better or do I have some mistake?

```
 <StaticImage src='../../images/welcome.svg'
   alt='a'
   placeholder='a'
   width={375}
   height={502}
   quality={100}
 />
```

[image]

```
<img src={image} alt='a' width='375' height='502' />
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that Gatsby Image (hence `StaticImage`) supports SVGs out of the box, that's why it's not applying any transformation.From the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image/#formats):

> **formats** Default component prop value: ["auto", "webp"]. Default resolver prop value: [AUTO, WEBP]
>
> The Gatsby Image plugin supports four output formats: JPEG, PNG, WebP
> and AVIF. By default, the plugin generates images in the same format
> as the source image, as well as WebP. For example, if your source
> image is a PNG, it will generate PNG and WebP images. In most cases,
> you should not change this. However, in some cases you may need to
> manually set the formats. One reason for doing so is if you want to
> enable support for AVIF images. AVIF is a new image format that
> results in significantly smaller file sizes than alternative formats.
> It currently has [limited browser support](https://caniuse.com/avif), but this is likely to
> increase. It is safe to include as long as you also generate fallbacks
> for other browsers, which the image plugin does automatically by
> default.

In your case, using an SVG, I'd suggest using the standards `<img>` tag or inlining the SVG directly using one of the multiple approaches suggested at [Import SVG as a component in Gatsby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61158924/import-svg-as-a-component-in-gatsby/61161331#61161331)

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with this issue. I found that using the prop `width` inside a `<StaticImage />` messes the resolution of the image. I'll explain with this example:
If i have an img element 100px wide i EXPECT that an picture with a resolution of 100px*100px  would look fine. So i use the component

`<StaticImage width={100} />`

In theory this should work right? well... no. The image is 100px wide, but the element is *actually* bigget than that in **real** pixels.

This is the basis of an HD screen, each computed px is actually made by multiple real px. So back to the example, if the **computed** size of the element is 100px, then the **real** size is (hypothetically) 200px.

Then, using the `width` prop inside a StaticImage component will prevent gatsby from downloading images bigger than the value provided. So the element is 200px wide, the image is still 100px wide, thus the image looks low quality.

As a fix i decided to not use the width prop, and just control the size of the img with Css.
This is probably the same with the hight prop but i didn't test that...